# Why do I keep getting a UnicodeEncodeError when trying to create an S3 bucket via aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I've been using the following command to successfully create S3 buckets:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket unique-bucket-name –region us-west-1
```

But today, without changing anything (aside from the unique bucket name of course), I'm getting the following error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 59, in main
    rc = driver.main()
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 210, in main
    sys.stderr.write(str(e))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The mentioned utf8 code is a hyphen i think, so i tried all en dashes, then all hyphens, but none of it changes the error message i get.  How do I get this command to go back to doing what it's supposed to do again?

Comment: The character before your `region` flag in your pasted command is a – rather than -

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the hyphens, and in particular it's the character before `region`. It is an en-dash. Change

```
–region
```

To

```
--region
```

That is, use two hyphens instead. (If you can't see the difference between an en-dash and a hyphen, copy the correction right out of this answer and paste it into your command.)

Comment: It should be 2 hyphens and I took the liberty to edit your answer.